# python sort a list by an alphabet

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list alphabetically - but with values containing `x` at the front.

```
def front_x(words):
    r = words
    s = []
    o = []
    for x in r:
        if "x" in x:
            s.append(x)
        else:
            o.append(x)
    return sorted(s,key = lambda f:f.find("x")) + sorted(o)

front_x(['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa'])
```

It currently returns `['xzz', 'xaa', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc']`,

I want to it to return `['xaa', 'xzz', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc']`

Comment: Hi Jawad, you need to include more detail in your question as well as format it a little cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to to this with just the `sorted` function.

Try something like this;

```
s = ['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa']
sorted(s, lambda w: ("x" in w, w))
```

This will sort the values containing "x" to the front, and then alphatical from then on.

If you want to only sort the values starting with "x" to the front (I'm not sure from your question), then you will need to tweak it slightly though;

```
sorted(s, lambda w: ("x" == w[:1], w))
```

Let me know if I haven't quite understood what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to reply my question, I tried your first method and it returned ['axx', 'xaa', 'xzz', 'bbb', 'ccc'], while I want the result to be
['xaa', 'xzz', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc'] , which means that i want to sort them out by "x" but it should sort the second char normally as the sorted() func does

Comment: hey bro I solved the problem the other simple way thanks :)

Comment: Usually you would upvote answers that helped get to your solution - and post your answer if you found it yourself.

Comment: okay i will post the answer sorry it is my first time asking question on this forum